# How to import template in polymer?

Tags: polymer

I want create template libraray in isolated file.

./my-components/templates.html

```
<template id="overTemplate">
    <div on-mouseover="{{mouseOverHandler}}">OVER</div>
</template>
.....
```

And connect this file in my polymer-element:

```
<link rel="import" href="./my-components/templates.html">
```

Then use this template:

```
<template bind ref="overTemplate"></template>
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about?

```
var link = document.querySelector('link[rel=import]');
var content = link.import.querySelector('#overTemplate');
document.body.appendChild(document.importNode(content, true));
```

Credits to Mr 'Polymer' Dodson...
http://robdodson.me/blog/2013/08/20/exploring-html-imports/

Polymer has a helper called import but as far as I can tell it is ready to import polymer-elements only.

Answer (score 1):

The above does not work with Polymer 1.0 as template annotation bindings are no longer dynamic based on DOM modifications. 
[There is a tag](https://github.com/Trakkasure/dom-bindref), currently a stop gap until the Polymer team provides that ability, that attempts to provide reference templates.