# HTML page as template of Polymer element

Tags: polymer-1.0

Is it possible to refer some HTML page as Polymer element's template? I have seen a few examples but local DOM of the elements only have HTML markup. I want something like:

```
<dom-module id="xyz-element">
    <template>
        <style>
            /* local DOM styles go here */
        </style>
        <!-- local DOM goes here -->
        <import src="any.html"/>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'xyz-element',
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting. Why do you need such feature?

Comment: Because my component comprises of a bigger HTML and I want to keep it outside the component definition file (sort of).

Comment: How about splitting your component into smaller elements?

Comment: That could be possible after re-analyzing the whole idea. Meanwhile I also want to know that is my idea possible with current version of Polymer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible as of version 0.8. See [How to import template in polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26614469/how-to-import-template-in-polymer)

If you intention is not to break up HTML portion into smaller parts but only separate it from the JS, then you can import the script instead:

```
<dom-module id="my-module">
   <template>
     <!-- all of your element's HTML goes here -->
   </template>
</dom-module>

<!-- all of your element's JS goes here -->
<script src="my-module.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what does my-module.js contains? Will it contain all HTML markup and then we need to place it in template tag using JavaScript?

Comment: No, the js file will contain only you Polymer definition (`Polymer()` call etc.). The usage is precisely as in the snippet above

Comment: It may be worth noting that the `<script>` can be both inside and outside `<dom-module>`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808629/should-my-script-be-inside-my-dom-module